# PHP Load Data Infile to MySQL Table Certain Columns

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a CSV file that I need to insert into a MySQL table. However the CSV file has a different number of columns to the table, and the columns are in a different order.

The table has these columns: 
**ID, Product_ID, Order_ID, Shipping_Name, Shipping_Postcode, Tracking_Number**

And the CSV has:
**Tracking_Number, Order_ID, Name, Postcode** 
(The Product ID is the name of the file and I can set this as a variable in PHP then update the column, so that's okay)

I know that you can create fake columns using @ in the query to skip certain columns in the table, but I am not sure how to link columns that are in a different order, or if it is even possible.

Here is my query that I use for when the columns match up:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/html/imports/tracking/$file'
    IGNORE INTO TABLE tracking
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (@product_id, @order_id, @shipping_name, @shipping_postcode, @tracking_number)
    SET Product_ID=@product_id, Order_ID=@order_id, Shipping_Name=@shipping_name, Shipping_Postcode=@shipping_postcode, Tracking_Number=@tracking_number";
```

Can I adjust this for what I need to acheive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not product_id so

just use the csv as position and the column table baded on indentier

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/html/imports/tracking/$file'
    IGNORE INTO TABLE tracking
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (@col1, @col2, @col3, @col4)
    SET  Order_ID=@col2, Shipping_Name=@col3, Shipping_Postcode=@col4, Tracking_Number=@col1";
```